# Code::Blocks - error: stray '\240'

Tags: c++

Estou enfrentando um problema simples, acredito. Salvo meu arquivo em `.cpp` no Code::Blocks e depois tento compilá-lo. Entretanto, quando compilo, aparece uns erros (Uso compilador minGW):

[image: Erros aparentemente se referem à bibliteca <iostream>]

Compiler settings:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso Windows 8.1. Alguém sabe como resolver? Código simples que apresenta os erros:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 cout << "Hello World!"; return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se colocar seu código talvez dê para ajudar. Só o erro complica. Eu até faço ideia, mas para responder preciso saber do que se trata mesmo.

Comment: O código fora adicionado no post.

Comment: Nenhum problema aqui: http://ideone.com/we0vY4 Será que gravou o arquivo com alguma codificação de texto que esteja causando problema?

Comment: Bom, acredito que não. Apenas programei em C, então não sei como configurar, veja meu settings do compilador no post. Eu o editei com a imagem, se puder me ajudar, fico grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como [mencionado pelo José](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/156879/6454), em alguma parte do teu código existem caracteres inesperados, assumindo que você esteja usando Unicode ou ISO-8859-1, `\240` pode representar o caractere [*non-breaking space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (espaço em branco que não permite quebra de linha).

Isso pode acontecer quando você copia o código de algum site, talvez por conter [caracteres não legíveis](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html) que o compilador não consegue entender (e você também não pode ver), uma outra causa pode ser a codificação que você esteja usando, você pode verificar em `Settings` ⇢ `Editor` ⇢ `Other Settings` ⇢ `Encoding`.

Crie um novo projeto e tente usar o código abaixo.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: É, resolveu. Muito obrigado, não sabia dessa!

Answer (score 1):

Erro de digitacão: tem um caracter inválido em algum lugar de seu fonte, provavelmente um "á".

\240 = 128 + 32 = 160 (Alt+160 no Windows é "á")

Comment: O código fora adicionado no post